# listbox performance in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Itemscontrol nested within a listbox.DataTemplate consits of image and border controls.The listbox scrolling is pretty slow.How can i improve its performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use virtualization. There are few examples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx) and [here](http://shawnoster.com/2010/08/improving-listbox-performance-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-data-virtualization/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend loading the Images using David Ansons's LowProfileImageLoader. You can find more abotu it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/10/04/there-s-no-substitute-for-customer-feedback-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-now-a-bit-easier-with-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx?Redirected=true) and [download a package from nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/PhonePerformance). It helped me a lot with performance issues when dealing with images. It is also very easy to use.